# sql: Scan error on column index 5, name "todos": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]datatypes.JSON golang gorm

Tags: arrays, json, database, go, go-gorm

This is the model:

```golang
type Board struct {
    Id     uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    Owner  uint `json:"owner"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Contributors []int `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"contributors"`
    GeneratedLink string `gorm:"default:''" json:"generated_link"`
    Todos []datatypes.JSON `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"todos"`
}

type TodoStructure struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
    Text string `json:"text"`
    Completed bool `json:"completed"`
    Important bool `json:"important"`
}
```

This is how i create the board:

```golang
board := models.Board{
    Owner:         20,
    Name:          "text",
    GeneratedLink: "",
    Todos: []datatypes.JSON{datatypes.JSON("[]")},
}

database.DB.Create(&board)
```

This is how column looks after creating board: [image]

so todos is just an empty array. And this is how i am creating todo:

```golang
func createTodo(c *gin.Context) {
    var board models.board
    database.DB.Where("id = ?", 1).First(&board)
    id := uuid.NewV4().String()
    todoStruct := models.TodoStructure{
        Id:        id,
        Text:      "text",
        Completed: false,
        Important: false,
    }

    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(todoStruct)
    board.Todos = append(board.Todos, jsonData)
    fmt.Println(board.Todos) //exactly what i need [{"id":"e7ee015ab54c48388aa2413428f76f50","text":"text","completed":false,"important":false}]
    database.DB.Save(&board)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"message": "success"})
}
```

but i got the error:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 5, name "todos": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]datatypes.JSON
```

and in column todo value saves like this:

[image]

[image]

just json object, but i need to save like this:

```
[{"id":"e7ee015ab54c48388aa2413428f76f50","text":"text","completed":false,"important":false}]
```

[image]

[image]

Please any ideas, any options, i tried to find the solution in the google but not found right solution.

P.S using gorm and postgresql

Comment: For `type:jsonb` use `datatypes.JSON`. i.e. drop the `[]`. The type `datatypes.JSON` *can* represent any valid JSON, including JSON arrays, i.e. for storing `[{"id":"123",...}]` it is appropriate. The type `[]datatypes.JSON` on the other hand represents a slice of *discrete* elements of type JSON, for that you would need `jsonb[]` (i.e. a jsonb array) in postgresql.

Comment: @mkopriva in model i dropped the `[]` and now it's just `datatypes.JSON` but now in create todo function i got the error: `Cannot use 'jsonData' (type []byte) as the type byte` [screenshot of an error](https://i.postimg.cc/rwHrntQh/Screen-Shot-2021-12-12-at-00-54-41.png)

Comment: Drop the append: `board.Todos = jsonData`

Comment: @mkopriva it saves as json object again, not like this: `[{"id":"e7ee015ab54c48388aa2413428f76f50","text":"text","completed":false,"important":false}]`

Comment: And if what you "exactly need" is an *array-of-objects* in the JSON, i.e. `[{"id": ...`, instead of just an object, i.e. `{"id": ...`, then you should `json.Marshal` a slice instead of just a single struct. i.e. you can do this: `json.Marshal([]models.TodoStructure{todoStruct})`.

Comment: @mkopriva That works, thanks, but also i need to append another JSON on every request, now i am just overwriting the `board.Todos` `board.Todos = jsonData` so how to append another JSON on another request? Anyway thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240052/discussion-between-rejs-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the incorrect data type. Can you try this line?

```
    Todos []byte `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"todos"`
```